# Why can't I obtain Facebook page's access token?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I successfully retrieve Facebook user's access token and pass it to generate page access token (with user's access token instead of XXX):

https://graph.facebook.com/409384220616262?fields=access_token&access_token=XXX

But it does not work:

`{"error":{"message":"(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (access_token) on node type (Application)","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"AT9gHnNwvygUy_bV3CDBoNa"}}`

What's wrong?

Comment: 409384220616262 is the page ID?

Comment: @WizKid Yes, it is.

Comment: No it is not. It is an Application just like the error message say.